# AndroidStudio (gradle): unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android-studio, gradle

При создании нового проекта вылетают такие ошибки, не могу понять как решить данную проблему. Кто либо знает решение? что с этим делать? ну и в чем сама суть проблемы?
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Зачем здесь этот скриншот, вместо нормального текста с ошибками?  Если проблемы с build.gradle почему его содержимого нет в вопросе? сама суть проблемы в том, что разглядывать эти скриншоты как то желания мало обычно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка вызвана из-за того, что в grable у Вас стоит targetSdkVersion (т.е. компилируется под Android, ну например, kitkat). Соответственно, в данной версии Android не существует такой библиотеки, как appcompact-v7 Попробуйте изменить параметр на 26 <
Если же вас не устраивает смена параметра у targetSdkVersion, тогда Вам необходимо подклчить более раннюю версию библиотеки.

Comment: Ох, я просто как бы, новичек в андроид, гредл, и толком еще не понимаю как все устроено. Можно подробнее?

Comment: Предлагаю начать чат, чтобы не злить модераторов, однако не хнаю как (((. Возможно вы хнаете.